# Android get GPS Address

Tags: android, gps, location

My app reads in and gives me the gps coordinates of my phone.

i then want to do a reverse geocode to give me the physical address

i use this code to do that

```
        double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
        double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
        try {
            List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);



        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

How do i now toast the address
im after some way of it showing the address of the coordinates on the screen

any help apprciated

mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using the google Geocoding API. Its a part of the google maps api, so you might not be able to use their api's for standalone calls, but its worth a shot.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding